# Do I have to start from beginning?

Tags: c++, arrays

If I have:

```
std::size_t bagCapacity_ = 10;
std::size_t bagSize = 0;
A** bag = new A*[bagCapacity_];

while (capacity--)
{
  bag[capacity] = new A(bagSize++); //**here I'm loading this array from the end is it ok?**
}
```

And also can I delete those object from starting at the end of the array?

```
while (capacity--)
{
  delete bag[capacity];
}
```

Question in a code.

Comment: why is bagCapacity in the std namespace?

Comment: It's not. `bagCapacity` is of type `std::size_t` (a type in the `std`) but that doesn't mean *itself* is in the `std` namespace.

Comment: @Akanksh: Formatting problem, already fixed.

Comment: Obligatory: Use `std::vector`!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
here I'm loading this array from the end is it ok?
```

Yes, that is fine. You can fill the elements anyway you like.

```
delete[] bag[capacity];
```

This code is wrong. bag[capacity] is of type `A*` which is allocated using `new` and not `new[]` hence you should not do `delete[]` you should do only `delete bag[capacity];` to delete individual `A` objects. At the end you should be `delete[] bag` to delete the memory allocated for the bag.

Answer (score 1):

There's no forced order to access an array, so your code is fine.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, once you've allocated the `bag` array, you can iterate over it however you want.  The point of arrays is to be randomly accessible in constant time.  What you're doing is fine.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure whether you want an array of arrays of A or an array of A pointers. If you want an array of arrays, then you should be doing

```
bag[capacity] = new A[bagSize++];
```

(note the square brackets) but otherwise the code looks good. However, if it's the second case (array of A pointers), then you should only do

```
delete[] bag;
```

(i.e. no delete[] in a loop).

Answer (score 1):

The code is fine except for the `delete` part. It should be `delete bag[capacity];` since you are not deleting the array but an instance of `A` that is a member of the array. After that, you should also perform `delete[] bag` to delete the allocated array for `bag`.

I'm wondering why you put `bagCapacity_` in `std` namespace? Perhaps you want it in your own namespace?

Answer (score 0):

There is one part of your code that's particularly disturbing:

```
std::bagCapacity_ = 10;
```

This seems to indicate that you're creating a variable named `bagCapacity` in the `std` namespace. Unless I'm misunderstanding what's going on here, this is strictly verboten -- there are only a *few* things you're allowed to add to the `std` namespace (primarily specializations of templates that are already there).

I'm also left wondering what you're doing here. Using `new[]` is nearly always a mistake. What you're writing looks suspiciously like a mediocre imitation of a `vector`, so unless this is something on the order of a class assignment intended to teach some specific (rather poor) technique, you'd probably be better off asking about what you're actually trying to accomplish, and getting advice about a good way to do that instead.

Answer (score 0):

It's quite OK to set array elements in any order. But you are missing delete[] operation!